# Cannot read property 'value' of null at addname

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create four inputs and display all of them after clicking the button. However it returns null. What's wrong with my code?

```js
function addname() {
  for (count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    var x = " ";
    var inputID = "clientname" + (count + 1);
    x = document.getElementById(inputID).value
  }

  var f = "";
  for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    f += x[count];
  }

  document.write(f)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clientname1" />
<input type="text" id="clientname2" />
<input type="text" id="clientname3" />
<input type="text" id="clientname4" />
<button onclick="addname()"></button>
```

Comment: Bit of a scope issue here to start with. Outside the first for loop, x is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Immediate fix: There are 4 inputs, not 5, and stop `x` from being abused:

```
function addname() {
  var names = [];
  for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
    var inputId = " clientname" + (count + 1);
    var name    = document.getElementById( inputId ).value;
    names.push( name );
  }

  var f = "";
  for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    f += names[count];
  }

  document.getElementById( 'output' ).textContent = f; // Never use `document.write`!
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="clientname1" />
<input type="text" id="clientname2" />
<input type="text" id="clientname3" />
<input type="text" id="clientname4" />
<button onclick="addname()">Concatenate names</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

#### Revision 2: Simplified: Using `querySelectorAll` with a substring attribute match, and `join` to concatenate strings:

```
function concatenateNames() {

    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=text][id^="clientname"]' );
    const names = []; // `const` means the variable cannot be reassigned, not that it's immutable.

    for( let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ )
    {
        names.push( inputs[i].value );
    }

    const allNames = names.join( " " );
    document.getElementById( 'output' ).textContent = allNames;
}
```

#### Revision 3: Simplified further, using `Array.from` so we can use `map` with `NodeListOf<T>`, and adding `filter` to exclude empty values:

```
function concatenateNames() {

    const inputs = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=text][id^="clientname"]' ) );

    const names = inputs.map( inputEl => inputEl.value ).filter( n => n.length > 0 );
    const allNames = names.join( " " );

    document.getElementById( 'output' ).textContent = allNames;
}
```

#### Revision 4: Simplified further, inlining intermediate variables only used once:

```
function concatenateNames() {

    document.getElementById( 'output' ).textContent =
        Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=text][id^="clientname"]' )
        )
        .map( inputEl => inputEl.value )
        .filter( n => n.length > 0 )
        .join( " " );
}
```

#### Revision 5: Using `nextElementSibling` and an inline `onclick` handler in a single line and shortening identifiers:

```html
<input type="text" id="clientname1" />
<input type="text" id="clientname2" />
<input type="text" id="clientname3" />
<input type="text" id="clientname4" />
<button onclick="this.nextElementSibling.textContent = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][id^=clientname]') ).map(i => i.value).filter(n => n.length > 0).join(' ')">Concatenate names</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Never do this in production code.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3md65awo/

Comment: Simplified example with map is the most readable one! Thank you for this. I wish more developer learn and write short and crisp but very readable and clean code like that.

Comment: Hi, I tried the immediate fix, but it's still turning" can't read property of null"?

Comment: @JiangYuxin Try "Revision 3" instead. What is the exact message in your browser's console and what does the debugger say?

Comment: @ThomasZuberbühler `map`, `filter`, etc are all parts of the functional programming mindset which is very difficult for novice programmers to get into. People know programs are "a series of instructions" - but functional-style programs do not make it obvious what those instructions are - and people get thrown-off by method chaining too. I feel the only people who can get into functional programming easily are people with a strong background in pure-mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript stops running at the error upon count = 4 trying to get element by id "clientname5"

Either add another text input or change loop to "count = 0; count < 4; count++"

Comment: Thank you. However when I changed it and it's still "can't read the property of null".

Comment: there are some other issues such as out of range x, but the loop should work after you match number or elements, probably you need to refresh the page

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I used jquery for this.

```js
function addname() {
      for (var count = 1; count < 5; count++) {
        var x;
        x = $("#clientname" +count).val() 
        console.log(x)

        $("#test").append(x)
      }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="inp" id="clientname1" />
    <input type="text" name="inp" id="clientname2" />
    <input type="text" name="inp" id="clientname3" />
    <input type="text" name="inp" id="clientname4" />
    <label id = "test"></label>
    <input type="button" onclick="addname()" value="click" />
```